# Calculate price and display on WooCommerce product single page under price (simple price, variable price)

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I am planing to show a new price on my WooCommerce product page for all products. This is the installment price per month. I need to show this below the normal price (variable price and simple price) something like this.

**0% interest installments starting from Rs.3,093**

where Rs.3,093 is the new price.

This is the calculation I tried on W3 schools, and I got the calculation correct.

whereas 60000 is the price of the product
multiplied by this number 5.15464
divided by 100

Answer is 3,093
(answer should be rounded off to the nearest integer)

I need a custom function for this that I can add to my functions.php

```js
<script>
var x = myFunction(60000, 5.15464, 100);
function myFunction(a, b, c) {
  return Math.round (a * b / c);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Do you want to completely alter the product price (new price take effect when user add to cart), or just display an alternative price below the original price?

Comment: I need to display an alternative price below the original price. just to let customer know that they can pay the amount in instalments. 

something like this

**0% interest free installments starting from Rs.2,500/Month**

where 2,500 is the price im looking to display on the woocommerce product page before the add to cart button

Comment: It looks like you want some PHP, but have supplied some JavaScript. It is OK to need this, but asking for whole pieces of code here is either Too Broad or Request For External Resources. Readers will generally encourage you to make a start on this yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will display the value or content before `Add to Cart` button in woocommerce product page.

```
        add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'show_emi', 20 );
      function show_emi() {
       global $product; 
       $id = $product->get_id();
        $product = wc_get_product( $id );
        $a=$product->get_price();
        $b  = 5.15464;
        $c = 100;
        $d = $a * $b;
        $total = $d/$c;
          echo $total;
      }
```

Comment: This is what i was looking for. This works great thanks, Now i wanted $a = woocommerce product price. so it will calculate from the product price and echo the total.  something like this.

-----<code>-----
 add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'show_emi', 20 );
      function show_emi() {
        $a .= woocommerce_price( $product->get_price() );
        $b  = 5.15464;
        $c = 100;
        $d = $a * $b;
        $total = $d/$c;
         echo '<span class="int">0% Instalments starting from <b>Rs. ' . $total . '/month</b> </span>';
      }
-----</code>------

Comment: Hey Glad to know that the above code worked and helped you, Can you please check my answer and upvote . Thanks!

Comment: Can i know how can i add the woocommerce product price to $a?

Comment: NO it doesn't. The code crashes. "The site is experiencing technical difficulties."

Comment: Can you let me know what is the error. Can you provide me your credentials to chekc

Comment: @Anas - this answer is already above and beyond what should be expected.  Please upvote and / or accept.  If you have additional questions, please ask a NEW question, don't keep asking for more via comments.

Comment: @Anas - additionally, the _version_ of WooCommerce matters.  They change functions sometimes between versions, and that may be the cause of your error.\

Comment: @cale_b got it, im new to stack!

Comment: @PullataPraveen i will check will the latest edited code, thanks

Comment: It's ok thanks Anas. If you have any issue happy to help you 

Comment: @PullataPraveen thanks alot, the latest code works (Y)

Comment: @PullataPraveen i have checked a mark to your answer. can you check this question too? https://stackoverflow.com/q/57470768/4690396