# How to calculated price in woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, shortcode, price

I need help:)

I want to make a paylater message on my product page. For example, I have a product that costs $55, and under it I want to put the "Pay in 4 interest-free payments of $13.75 with us" message which $13.75 is calculated automatically.

I've already found the code (shortcode) because I want the output in the form of a shortcode.

```
add_shortcode( 'product_price', 'display_product_price' );
function display_product_price( $atts ){
    $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
        'id' => get_the_id(),
    ), $atts, 'product_price' );
    global $product;
    if ( ! is_a( $product, 'WC_Product') )
        $product = wc_get_product($atts['id']);
    return $product->get_price();
}
```

But I don't know how to add the formula in that code, and that code doesn't show the currency symbol. Please help me to add a formula to that code, and bring up the currency symbol($).

I would be very grateful for any help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this case allready solved, I'll answer maybe someone will need something like this...

I found this guy's code [praveen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5408567/praveen) from his answer on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57443892/calculate-price-and-display-on-woocommerce-product-single-page-under-price-simp).

This is my modification code to fit in my case

```
        add_shortcode( 'price_calculated', 'display_price_calculated' );
        function display_price_calculated( $atts ){ //create shortcode
               global $product; 
               $id = $product->get_id(); //get current product id
                $product = wc_get_product( $id );
                $a=$product->get_price(); //get current product price
                $b  = 4; //because I want my price to be divided in 4
                $total = $a/$b; //calculated formula
                return get_woocommerce_currency_symbol().$total; //Show the price result, and add a currency symbol before price result
              }
```

Now I just need to add this shortcode [price_calculated]
on my page

That's it, thanks stack StackOverflow!